# Initialise Twilio chat client getting error response as Operation has been canceled, unable to set FPA token in ANDROID

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

On initialising **Twilio chat client**, I am getting Error response as

> 1. (errorInfo.getMessage: Operation has been canceled, unable to set FPA token)
> 2. (error status from errorInfo.getstatus: 0) and
> 3. (errorInfo.getCode: 2)

It was initialising successfully But now its giving error response, not creating Chat Client successfully.

I'm stuck on this. please help.... thanks in advance.

PHP Code i am using to fetch access token

```html
<?php
include('vendor/autoload.php');
include('./randos.php');


use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\SyncGrant;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\ChatGrant;

// Load environment variables from .env, or environment if available
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// An identifier for your app - can be anything you'd like
$appName = 'TwilioStarterDemo';

// print_r($urlPoster);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data["identity"];

$identity   = $data['identity'];
// A device ID should be passed as a query string parameter to this script
$deviceId   = $data['deviceId']; //'somedevice';
$endpointId = $appName . ':' . $identity . ':' . $deviceId;

// Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client
$token = new AccessToken(getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'), getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'), 3600, $identity);

// Grant access to Video
$grant = new VideoGrant();
$token->addGrant($grant);

// Grant access to Sync
$syncGrant = new SyncGrant();
if (empty(getenv('TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID'))) {
    $syncGrant->setServiceSid('default');
} else {
    $syncGrant->setServiceSid(getenv('TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID'));
}
$token->addGrant($syncGrant);

// Grant access to Chat
if (!empty(getenv('TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID'))) {
    $chatGrant = new ChatGrant();
    $chatGrant->setServiceSid(getenv('TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID'));
    $chatGrant->setEndpointId($endpointId);
    
    $token->addGrant($chatGrant);
}


// return serialized token and the user's randomly generated ID
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array(
    'identity' => $identity,
    'token' => $token->toJWT(),
    'deviceId' => $deviceId
));
```

access token which i am getting

```html
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzLTE1MTE5MzMzMzYiLCJpc3MiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzIiwic3ViIjoiQUMzMTA0YzE2ZWJhNTg5ODEyZjAyNDcwNGU3NmUzYzZlMyIsImV4cCI6MTUxMTkzNjkzNiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoicmFmaXEiLCJ2aWRlbyI6e30sImRhdGFfc3luYyI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQifSwiY2hhdCI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6IklTZGNlZmFmOGU4OWZlNDk5MDhhMWZkZmRlOTllYjg0NmEiLCJlbmRwb2ludF9pZCI6IlR3aWxpb1N0YXJ0ZXJEZW1vOnJhZmlxOjFmYmRjYTg1YmU1NjMyMGQifX19.e_8s9jErDpeCM0mdIc-RfHpskM5Z3eBloj7ZI3HDOl4
```

Logs of the code

```html
D/TwilioAdminAccessToken: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzLTE1MTE5MzMzMzYiLCJpc3MiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzIiwic3ViIjoiQUMzMTA0YzE2ZWJhNTg5ODEyZjAyNDcwNGU3NmUzYzZlMyIsImV4cCI6MTUxMTkzNjkzNiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoicmFmaXEiLCJ2aWRlbyI6e30sImRhdGFfc3luYyI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQifSwiY2hhdCI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6IklTZGNlZmFmOGU4OWZlNDk5MDhhMWZkZmRlOTllYjg0NmEiLCJlbmRwb2ludF9pZCI6IlR3aWxpb1N0YXJ0ZXJEZW1vOnJhZmlxOjFmYmRjYTg1YmU1NjMyMGQifX19.e_8s9jErDpeCM0mdIc-RfHpskM5Z3eBloj7ZI3HDOl4
I/System.out: token updated.
D/AdminChat: token Updated
D/AdminChat: Building client 
D/TWC: ChatClient(native):        -1304996556 | 11/29/10:58:56.517 | DEBUG    | ChatClient(native) | Started ChatClient nativeCreate()
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46f14 for method onMessageAdded(Lcom/twilio/chat/Message;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46f5c for method onMessageUpdated(Lcom/twilio/chat/Message;Lcom/twilio/chat/Message$UpdateReason;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46f38 for method onMessageDeleted(Lcom/twilio/chat/Message;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46ea8 for method onMemberAdded(Lcom/twilio/chat/Member;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46ef0 for method onMemberUpdated(Lcom/twilio/chat/Member;Lcom/twilio/chat/Member$UpdateReason;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46ecc for method onMemberDeleted(Lcom/twilio/chat/Member;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46fc8 for method onTypingStarted(Lcom/twilio/chat/Member;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46fa4 for method onTypingEnded(Lcom/twilio/chat/Member;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d46f80 for method onSynchronizationChanged(Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d4806c for method onChannelJoined(Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d48048 for method onChannelInvited(Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d48000 for method onChannelAdded(Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d480b4 for method onChannelUpdated(Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel;Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel$UpdateReason;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d48024 for method onChannelDeleted(Lcom/twilio/chat/Channel;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d48144 for method onNotification(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d4818c for method onNotificationSubscribed()V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d48168 for method onNotificationFailed(Lcom/twilio/chat/ErrorInfo;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d481f8 for method onUserUpdated(Lcom/twilio/chat/User;Lcom/twilio/chat/User$UpdateReason;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d481b0 for method onUserSubscribed(Lcom/twilio/chat/User;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d481d4 for method onUserUnsubscribed(Lcom/twilio/chat/User;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d480d8 for method onClientSynchronization(Lcom/twilio/chat/ChatClient$SynchronizationStatus;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d480fc for method onConnectionStateChange(Lcom/twilio/chat/ChatClient$ConnectionState;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d48120 for method onError(Lcom/twilio/chat/ErrorInfo;)V
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d4addc for method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V
D/TWC::        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    |  | Root certificat store already initialized
D/TWC: ChatClient(native):        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | ChatClient(native) | Creating notification client observer
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | client: version: 2.4.0, build id: 236, build branch: master, os: android, arch: x86
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Default thread pool: Available: 16; Capacity: 16
I/TWC: TNHttpTransportClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | INFO     | 63     | TNHttpTransportClient | initialising...
I/TWC: TNHttpTransportClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | INFO     | 63     | TNHttpTransportClient | initialised
D/TWC: TCEmsClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | 65     | TCEmsClient | TCEmsClient
D/TWC: ChatContinuationTokenStorage(native):        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | ChatContinuationTokenStorage(native) | ChatContinuationTokenStorage::ChatContinuationTokenStorage(jni_mate::GlobalRef<_jobject*>)
D/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | init
D/TWC: TCEmsClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.529 | DEBUG    | 65     | TCEmsClient | init
D/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.530 | DEBUG    | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | setToken, eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzLTE1MTE5MzMzMzYiLCJpc3MiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzIiwic3ViIjoiQUMzMTA0YzE2ZWJhNTg5ODEyZjAyNDcwNGU3NmUzYzZlMyIsImV4cCI6MTUxMTkzNjkzNiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoicmFmaXEiLCJ2aWRlbyI6e30sImRhdGFfc3luYyI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQifSwiY2hhdCI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6IklTZGNlZmFmOGU4OWZlNDk5MDhhMWZkZmRlOTllYjg0NmEiLCJlbmRwb2ludF9pZCI6IlR3aWxpb1N0YXJ0ZXJEZW1vOnJhZmlxOjFmYmRjYTg1YmU1NjMyMGQifX19.e_8s9jErDpeCM0mdIc-RfHpskM5Z3eBloj7ZI3HDOl4
D/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.530 | DEBUG    | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | scheduleSetToken
I/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:58:56.530 | INFO     | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | schedule new task
D/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.531 | DEBUG    | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | internal set token run...
D/TWC: TCEmsClient:        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.531 | DEBUG    | 65     | TCEmsClient | setToken
D/TWC: TCEmsClient:        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.531 | DEBUG    | 65     | TCEmsClient | runGenerateTokenTask
D/TWC: ChatContinuationTokenStorage(native):        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.531 | DEBUG    | ChatContinuationTokenStorage(native) | std::__1::string retrieveTokenFromStorage(std::__1::string, jni_mate::GlobalRef<_jobject*>)
D/TWC: ChatContinuationTokenStorage(native):        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.531 | DEBUG    | ChatContinuationTokenStorage(native) | virtual std::__1::string ChatContinuationTokenStorage::fetchContinuationToken(const string&) retrieved token `` under key default
D/TWC: TCHttpObserver:        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.531 | DEBUG    | 66     | TCHttpObserver | client: version: 2.4.0, build id: 236, build branch: master, os: android, arch: x86
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.539 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | connectImpl >> Disconnected
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.539 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | connect
I/TWC: TNDisconnectedState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.540 | INFO     | 2      | TNDisconnectedState | Leaving state: Disconnected
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.540 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Change state: Disconnected --> Transport connecting
I/TWC: TNTransportConnectingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.540 | INFO     | 9      | TNTransportConnectingState | Entering state: Transport connecting
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.540 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | startTransportConnectingTimer
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:56.541 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Connecting...
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:56.541 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Using proxy : except ()
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:56.541 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Trying to establish connection to: https://tsock.us1.twilio.com
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.543 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | addObserverImpl >> Transport connecting
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.543 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | addObserver
I/TWC: TNHttpTransportClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:56.543 | INFO     | 63     | TNHttpTransportClient | twilsock is in disconnected state: Unknown reason
I/TWC: TNHttpTransportClient:        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.547 | INFO     | 63     | TNHttpTransportClient | requestId=RQ253710f7d4e94a90b549db06f6243f50, enqueueing request to: https://ems.us1.twilio.com/v1/token
D/TWC: TCEmsClient:        -2143557344 | 11/29/10:58:56.548 | DEBUG    | 65     | TCEmsClient | setToken - end
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.540 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onTransportConnectedImpl >> Transport connecting
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.540 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | sendInit
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.548 | INFO     | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | sendInit, id = 287f2315600c4ea3a2b10361e4a2e12ce12c
I/TWC: TNTransportConnectingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.548 | INFO     | 9      | TNTransportConnectingState | Leaving state: Transport connecting
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.549 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | stopTransportConnectingTimer
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.549 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Change state: Transport connecting --> Initialising
I/TWC: TNInitialisingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:58.549 | INFO     | 10     | TNInitialisingState | Entering state: Initialising
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:58.550 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Sending frame via websocket (677)
                    TWILSOCK V3.0 656
                    {"id":"287f2315600c4ea3a2b10361e4a2e12ce12c","method":"init","token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzLTE1MTE5MzMzMzYiLCJpc3MiOiJTSzg1OWEzZjM4ZDFmYzRkMmRhMDllYzNmYmEwMjc5NzIzIiwic3ViIjoiQUMzMTA0YzE2ZWJhNTg5ODEyZjAyNDcwNGU3NmUzYzZlMyIsImV4cCI6MTUxMTkzNjkzNiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoicmFmaXEiLCJ2aWRlbyI6e30sImRhdGFfc3luYyI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQifSwiY2hhdCI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6IklTZGNlZmFmOGU4OWZlNDk5MDhhMWZkZmRlOTllYjg0NmEiLCJlbmRwb2ludF9pZCI6IlR3aWxpb1N0YXJ0ZXJEZW1vOnJhZmlxOjFmYmRjYTg1YmU1NjMyMGQifX19.e_8s9jErDpeCM0mdIc-RfHpskM5Z3eBloj7ZI3HDOl4"}
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.162 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Receive message 136 bytes
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onMessageReceived (153)
                         TWILSOCK V3.0 132
                         {"method":"reply","id":"287f2315600c4ea3a2b10361e4a2e12ce12c","payload_size":0,"status":{"code":401,"status":"Authentication fail"}}
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onMessageReceived, method = 8, id = 287f2315600c4ea3a2b10361e4a2e12ce12c
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | proceedReplyMessage 287f2315600c4ea3a2b10361e4a2e12ce12c
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Receive message 136 bytes
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onMessageReceived (151)
                         TWILSOCK V3.0 130
                         {"method":"close","id":"TMf3a930b4f9e24656ac8d00830e40c2b3","payload_size":0,"status":{"code":401,"status":"Authentication fail"}}
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onMessageReceived, method = 3, id = TMf3a930b4f9e24656ac8d00830e40c2b3
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | proceedCloseMessage TMf3a930b4f9e24656ac8d00830e40c2b3
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:        -2145646304 | 11/29/10:58:59.163 | INFO     | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | Server has just initiated process of closing connection! 401: Authentication fail
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.164 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Reply for '287f2315600c4ea3a2b10361e4a2e12ce12c'
W/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.164 | WARNING  | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Reply status for init request is not success: 401, Authentication fail
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.164 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | ReceivedErrorInitReply >> Initialising
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.164 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | notifyAboutError
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.164 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | disconnect
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.165 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Disconnect
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.165 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Reset session
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:59.165 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Disconnecting...
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:59.419 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Disconnected
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:59.419 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onDisconnected
I/TWC: TNInitialisingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.420 | INFO     | 10     | TNInitialisingState | Leaving state: Initialising
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.420 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Change state: Initialising --> TransportDisconnecting
I/TWC: TNTransportDisconnectingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 11     | TNTransportDisconnectingState | Entering state: TransportDisconnecting
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | stopUpstreamRequests
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | sendSuccessReplyImpl >> TransportDisconnecting
W/TWC: TNTransportDisconnectingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | WARNING  | 11     | TNTransportDisconnectingState | Success reply can not be sent. Twilsock is not in connected state
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | closeRemotelyImpl >> TransportDisconnecting
W/TWC: TNTransportDisconnectingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | WARNING  | 11     | TNTransportDisconnectingState | Disconnect procedure has been already started
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | onDisconnectedImpl >> TransportDisconnecting
I/TWC: TNTransportDisconnectingState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 11     | TNTransportDisconnectingState | Leaving state: TransportDisconnecting
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Change state: TransportDisconnecting --> Disconnected
I/TWC: TNDisconnectedState:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | INFO     | 2      | TNDisconnectedState | Entering state: Disconnected
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.421 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | notifyAboutDisconnected
I/TWC: TNHttpTransportClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | INFO     | 63     | TNHttpTransportClient | twilsock is in disconnected state: Unknown reason
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | reset
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | ~TNWebsocket - begin
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Reset session
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Disconnecting...
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | Disconnected
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2132199712 | 11/29/10:58:59.422 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | close
D/TWC: TNWebsocket:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.423 | DEBUG    | 67     | TNWebsocket | ~TNWebsocket - end
I/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:         2133244192 | 11/29/10:58:59.423 | INFO     | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | stopUpstreamRequests
D/TWC: TNHttpTransportClient:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 63     | TNHttpTransportClient | dequeueing request: RQ253710f7d4e94a90b549db06f6243f50
D/TWC: TCHttpObserver:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 66     | TCHttpObserver | onCanceled - begin
D/TWC: TCHttpObserver:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 66     | TCHttpObserver | setPromise - 2
D/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | internal set token result: 2
I/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | INFO     | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | backoff result: 1 - 'Cancelled by user', setToken result: 2
D/TWC: TCBackoffEmsClient:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 64     | TCBackoffEmsClient | scheduleSetToken
D/TWC: TCEmsClient:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 65     | TCEmsClient | runGenerateTokenTask
D/TWC: TCHttpObserver:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.556 | DEBUG    | 66     | TCHttpObserver | onCanceled - end
D/TWC: TCHttpObserver:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 66     | TCHttpObserver | ~TCHttpObserver - begin
D/TWC: TCHttpObserver:        -2112984800 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 66     | TCHttpObserver | ~TCHttpObserver - end
D/jni_mate: Got method ID 0x86d499fc for method <init>(ILjava/lang/String;)V
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | ~TNTwilsockClient - begin
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Cleaning observers list - begin
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Cleaning observers list - end
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | cleanup_threads - begin
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.557 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | Default thread pool: Available: 16; Capacity: 16
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.558 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | cleanup_threads - end
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClient:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.558 | DEBUG    | 61     | TNTwilsockClient | ~TNTwilsockClient - end
D/TWC: TNTwilsockClientImpl:        -2035873504 | 11/29/10:59:01.558 | DEBUG    | 62     | TNTwilsockClientImpl | destructed
```

Comment: What code are you using to create your access token? Can you share an example of the access token here?

Comment: i am using php code to fetch access token.

Comment: Can you share your code and an example of the access token?

Comment: I shared the code and example of access token including logs.

Comment: I don't really know what's going on here. Your access token looks fine and if it was working before and just stopped then something else might be the issue. Firstly, I'd try generating a new API Key and Secret and using that in the access token. If that doesn't work, then I'd get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and explain what's going on and send them that error log too.

Comment: I even created new chat service then new api key and secret key didn't worked for this case also same issue and after trying this i created new twilio account and tried with the new account still the same issue.

Comment: Then I definitely recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). It looks right to me and your access token you shared seems fine. There must be something else going on. Are you behind some sort of restrictive network when testing this? Also, you did say that it used to work, was there anything that changed in your code between it working and not working?

Comment: No i didn't changed anything. I even rised a ticket in Twilio support. still no response from them. since i am using trail version i am not able to track the ticket history.

Comment: I need to implement this chat for my android app. please help .... i am stuck on this.

Comment: Support have your ticket and are looking into it. Hopefully you will hear soon!

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to connect to dev instance using a prod token or vice versa?

Comment: Also, `$chatGrant->setEndpointId($endpointId);` is no longer necessary.

Comment: yes im trying to connect using prod token

Comment: ill try by commenting the above mentioned line.

Comment: i tried by commenting that line but its not working

Comment: Something is wrong in the token which i am getting from php code. Can anyone help me out on this. please

Comment: @sham did you solve the problem? I seem to have the same error sometimes.